# What is the difference between getCurrentPosition and PositionStream geolocator flutzer

Tags: flutter, geolocator

I am using the geolocator package in my flutter app and I have some understanding issue.
GetCurrentPosition gives back the device current position and PositionStream updates the device location continuously.
So what is the difference between the two.
Can I use only PositionStream?
I want to track the device location at any time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getCurrentPosition` when you want to retrieve the position once and `getPositionStream` when you want to monitor the location over a time window. With `getPositionStream` you can adjust the distance a device has to travel or/and a timeout before the event is triggered. You can find the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Geolocator-class.html).